# Boost Spirit Phoenix function error

Tags: boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

This code is from the examples for boost spirit libs, it's OK:

```
on_error<fail>(expr,error_handler_function(eh)("expecting ", _4, _3));
```

However, this code failed to compile in Xcode:

```
on_error<fail>(expr,error_handler_function(eh)("expecting ", _4, _3, _1));
```

The error message:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/detail/function_eval.hpp:115:30:
    error: too many template arguments for class template 'result'

    fn::template result<BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(N, a)>
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The `eh(error_handle)` is right, I added the argument for the `_1`.

Comment: Don't just _claim_ "The `eh(error_handle)` is right", show it! It's essential to the error (and, one might say, it's obviously not right :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added the argument, but failed to add a template argument.

It needs to be a template argument because Phoenix expects fully polymorphic functors.

---

Potentially (depending on compiler and library versions), you can remove some of the restrictions by using

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
// and/or
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```